# How to implement face recognition in Flutter apps?

Tags: flutter, face-recognition

I am making an app in flutter. I would like to implement a feature where user can upload a image from database and it goes through a series of previously uploaded images on the firebase storage and returns if there's a match for the people in the database. How would I go about implementing this, simple and fast. A way to just compare two images passed on to a method will also be fine.

Comment: I not posted an answer because there no one absolutely method. But I tell you my approach. You need a mandatory process before get some picture and tell hey you are John Doe.   You need capture all persons picture maybe into register way and train some model appending this new neural data. When in future you get picture of some person previously trained into your trained model your algorithm tells you how much this imputed picture looks like someone, based into your desired score of match, you decide if there a correct match or not.

Comment: Try using this package: google_mlkit_face_detection: ^0.4.0. https://pub.dev/packages/google_mlkit_face_detection. If you need more help let me know

Comment: @Prashant He was asking for Face Recognition. Your package only helps for Face Detection which is something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is: take a look on face_recognotion lib (based on dlib) just to get better understanding how to compare faces, what face vectorization is and how to compare that vectors (or so called "face encodings" or "face embeddings")). That understanding may push you to an idea that you need to store not only face image files but face embedding too to be able to compare them. Then you could start to think either your Firebase has in-built functionality to index and compare that face embeddings (vectors).. or you should find a db server that has (Elasticsearch, for example)..
Then read about Google Mediapipe - probably the fastest framework for object recognition for mobile apps.

Comment: Thank you. Learnt a lot after reading through all of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`local_auth: ^2.1.2` for local authentication.